# Unable to open Universal Links in email on iOS using SendGrid

Tags: c#, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, sendgrid

I currently have the [Ionic Plugin Deeplink](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks.git) working for iOS when navigating from my web page.  So if a user clicks a link in Safari on their mobile everything works as expected and my app launches.  However, I have tried to use the same link in an email being sent from my server and I cannot get it to work.  I at first just set a property on the instantiation of my SendGridMessage to disable click tracking and then took it one step further to disable it on the actual settings at the SendGrid site for all emails.  Still nothing has worked.

Nothing happens when

- I set `href="myApp://myLocation"`
- I set `href="myApp://myLocation"` and `data-saferedirecturl="myApp://myLocation"`

If I only set the `data-saferedirecturl` Safari does open, but I receive:

```
"Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"
```

What else do I need to do to get the app to open from inside an email?

**Update**

I have now hooked up Android which works from my website as well.  It also works with an email from Hotmail, but not my Gmail.  Even though it is the same email when I inspect the element in Gmail I do not see the href....  Here is a run down of my tests:

Android from Hotmail:

- Works with href

Android from Gmail:

- Does not work with href, both href and data-saferedirecturl, or just the data-saferedirecturl

iOS from Hotmail or Gmail:

- Does not work with href, both href and data-saferedirecturl, or just data-saferedirecturl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realized that my problem probably had nothing to do with SendGrid or the plugin, but Gmail itself.  I could not find much on it, however I did finally come across the following [Apps Flyer site](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032266-Setting-Deeplinking-on-iOS9-using-iOS-Universal-Links) which stated at the bottom in the limitations:

> Gmail and Google Inbox apps do not handle Universal Links​ properly, they do not open the apps.  As a result, you are unable to open any app using universal links in these apps. As a workaround, you should use the iOS native mail application.

For now I am just linking from the website since that always works and will circle back around to email a little later.